# How to check if Virtual Path exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I programmatically check if a MVC Route exists?

Say I have this piece of code:

```
var virtualPath = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, routeValues);
```

I'd like to check if there's a matching controller and action for the generated route at virtualPath.Route.

I tried with GetRouteData but it returns null even for valid routes.

Comment: Why exactly do you need that?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'm translating routes dinamically using some extensions and want to decide when to use the real route or when to use the "translated alias"

Comment: I update my answer with working method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get RouteValueDictionary from `virtualPath`, then use reflection to check if exists controller and action for this routevalues

**Update:**
Sample method (I try it. It works):

```
public static bool CheckRoute(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(requestContext.HttpContext);
        if (routeData == null)
            return false;
        var controllerName = (string)routeData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string) routeData.Values["action"];
        var controller = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
        if (controller == null)
            return false;
        var controllerType = controller.GetType();
        var controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerType);
        var actionDescriptors = controllerDescriptor.GetCanonicalActions();
        return actionDescriptors.Select(a => a.ActionName).Contains(actionName);
    }
```